# Monaca.io can not build with adding cordova google map plugin

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, monaca

I am working on Monaca.io and try to build android with Google maps plugin by the structions from [cordova plugin google maps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Tutorial-for-Monaca)

After build it shown error below:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.
>   > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
>
> You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>   However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
>
> Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 10.305 secs

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

From within Monaca, go to Config -> Manage Plugins.  Remove and reinstall the plugin via uploading the master.zip which can be found here:  https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

The tutorial you linked to and the instructions followed were for Cordova 3.X.  Monaca IDE is currently using 5.2.0.  As such and as the tutorial states, the guide will no longer work as it generates the errors you describe.